# Signature of std::function when accepting a variadic lambda

Tags: c++, lambda

Suppose I have a lambda and a class; I want to assign the lambda to the class as a static variable. How could I do that?

```
auto func = [](void* p, auto&&... args) { /* do things */};
class A {
  static std::function<void(void*, ???)> f_;
};
```

I am not very sure what to put in the question marks. I tried

```
class A {
  template<class...Arg>
  static std::function<void(void*, Arg...)> f_;
};
```

But when I assign like

```
A::f_ = func;
```

Then it is complaining about `invalid use of incomplete type ‘class std::function<void(void*, Arg ...)>’`

Please help!

Comment: `static decltype(func) f_ = func;` Why does it have to be `std::function`?

Comment: Because I intend to templatize class A, so that each specialization will have a different signature depending on `func_` assigned to it.

Comment: `std::function` only provides one non-templated overload of `operator()`, its signature determined by the template parameter. There is no magic by which you can make `A::f_` callable with different number of arguments if `f_` is a `std::function`. It's not clear to me what you are trying to achieve, but `std::function` won't get you there.

Comment: *" I intend to templatize class A"*. You can: `template<class...Arg> class A {
  static std::function<void(void*, Arg...)> f_;
};`, So `A<int>` would have `std::function<void*, int>`.

Answer (score 2):

`std::function` is a function wrapper; it is not a function template wrapper. It has to have a specific set of arguments. You can do this for example for argument list `int, double, float`:

```
inline static std::function<void(void*, int, float, double)> f_ = func;
```

---

> I want to assign the lambda to the class as a static variable.

Then, perhaps it would be better to not wrap it in a `std::function`:

```
inline static decltype(func) f_ = func;
```

---

> But when I assign like
>
> ```
> A::f_ = func;
> ```
>
> Then it is complaining about ...

This is because you didn't pass the template arguments to the template variable. This would work:

```
A::f_<int, double, float> = func;
```